# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@124d2e11

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

"I am encountering problems compiling due to this error

```
Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@124d2e11.
```

Additionally, I am receiving the following error related to the values.xml file:

```
C:\Users\David\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d124191bb976fb106ae24aac2809574f\transformed\fragment-1.6.0\res\values\values.xml:3:4: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
```

Here is the content of the values.xml file in question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="fragment_container_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="special_effects_controller_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <item name="visible_removing_fragment_view_tag" type="id"/>
    <declare-styleable name="Fragment">
        <attr name="android:name"/>
        <attr name="android:id"/>
        <attr name="android:tag"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="FragmentContainerView">
        <attr name="android:name"/>
        <attr name="android:tag"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The error points to line 3, column 4 of the values.xml file. I understand that the error is related to the declaration of the <item> element in the values.xml file, but I am having difficulty identifying the exact problem and how to fix it.

Could someone help me understand what is causing this error and how I can fix it?

---

I attempted to build my Android project using Android Studio. I expected the build process to complete successfully without any errors. However, during compilation, I encountered the error mentioned above related to the values.xml file. This error disrupted the build process and prevented me from successfully compiling the project.